# Perl: Website Templates Collection

Tags: perl, templates, web

Have there been any projects that have a collection of perl web templates? Like on github or source forge?

There are tons of HTML/CSS templates out there, but are there any open source collections that have a framework already set up for different site genres/functionality (possibly using HTML::Template)?

It'd be nice to see pre-constructed wireframes, some that use pagination, some that have database connections, user logins, set up.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn´t. But is easy to adapt any HTML/CSS template to do this. I love this one: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: @MiguelPrz I had bootstrap in mind, but I'm in the process of building my own wireframe for future projects, which has jQuery, bootstrap, and a few others loaded by default.  My thought is "someone has to have already done this" and set up different wireframes for different content, different modules based on UI/Server interactions - I'm not talking about libraries/modules to perform the action, but pre-constructed barebones sites.

Answer (score 2):

In the Perl world, what we tend to call a "template" is more of a "fill in the blanks to create this specific page" kind of thing.  It doesn't create or define any program-level functionality, it just presents the functionality of the underlying code to the user.  e.g., The template will display controls that the user can use to navigate to other pages, but it does not implement pagination.  It displays "username" and "password" input fields, but it knows nothing about databases, sessions, or validating credentials.  Etc.

It sounds to me like you're looking more for what the Perl community refers to as a "web application framework", and there are several of them out there.  The big three right now are [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/), [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/), and [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

If you *really* want to commingle your templates and your functionality, I believe that [Mason](https://metacpan.org/module/Mason) works that way, but I would encourage you to look first at the other frameworks and try building thing with a clean separation of concerns - framework code only providing the functionality; templates only providing a user interface - before jumping into mixing functional code into the presentation layer in the old-school PHP style.

Comment: Dave, I'm saying to take it a step further.  I haven't had much success with Catalyst, but am familiar with Mojolicious.  What I'm looking for are barebone pre-constructed sites, which have different setups by default.  Because it is Perl, I was assuming that there might already be some using a Perl-Templating package (as you pointed out).... but I'm looking for HTML templates already setup and implemented with Perl backends - does that make sense?

Comment: OK, yes, that does make sense, but I've not seen anything like that other than the reusable bits that people tend to accumulate over the course of multiple projects.